# Ubuntu 16.04 partition doesn't boot after resizing

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, kernel

I hope you guys can help me because I'm beginning to be hopeless to find my data and all my work...
I spent 2 days going through many forums to find a solution but nothing works.

This is my problem:
I have a dual boot Windows 8.1/ubuntu 16.04 on my HP pavillion 15 
I am new to ubuntu and need it for my university work. I already worked few weeks on it and everything was fine, until I ran out of space on my linux partition. I decided to enlarge it following the tutorial [here](https://www.diskgenius.com/manual/resize-partition.php). However, after this was completed, my linux partition got stuck on a purple screen (blank purple screen without the ubuntu logo). 
I tried many tutorials saying to press different buttons while in this screen, adding nomodeset, trying to use older kernels (the latter worked once and after rebooting it doesn't work anymore), going into recovery mode and type fsck ... (but I don't have the command fsck, it says not found).

Now, each time I try to boot my linux partition, it goes into an error saying “end Kernel panic – not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(0,0)” and is stuck here.

When I run an older kernel in recovery mode I get
" BusyBox v1.22.1 (Ubuntu 1:1.22.0-15ubuntu1.4) built-in shell (ash)
Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands.

(initramfs):
"

but I can't type fsck in there..

Can someone help me please ? 
I really need to get this partition working very quickly because I have my dissertation work on it. :(

PS: my windows partition works perfectly.

Comment: To get your data you can boot a live system and copy it to an external hd, usb. Resizing partitions can be very dangerous.

Comment: thanks, good to know, but I also don't want to loose all the softwares I'm using because it takes ages to download and set everything correttly

Comment: Maybe someone very savvy knows hot to recover a rezised partition... but as far as I know it may not be possible.

Comment: As recommended do a backup and then why can't you type fsck, what is the error message you see?

Comment: I just deleted my partition and reinstalled Ubuntu, seemed to be the only way...
There was no command fsck, when i typed it it was saying not found, and when i typed help to see the possible commands, it was not here